# Q_ASSERT(unindexedItems.isEmpty())fails

Tags: c++, qt, open-source

I define a function:

```
void RealTimeMonitor::simulateMove(const QVector<QPointF> &path)
{
//pForklifts_[0] is a QGraphicsItem*,I want to move it along the path.
//omit some irrespective code just...
    pForklifts_[0]->setPos(x, y);
}
```

If I call the fun directly,everything go well.But,when I call the fun in a std::thread like:

```
std::thread threadSimulateMove(&RealTimeMonitor::simulateMove, this, path);
threadSimulateMove.detach();
```

I will get error as title show.I try to trace qt source,but have no much time and do not understand **unindexedItems**'s role.--**unindexedItems** is a member variable in **class QGraphicsSceneBspTreeIndexPrivate** which define in **qgraphicsscenebsptreeindex_p.h**.

Comment: After you created the thread, do you keep the `RealTimeMonitor` object alive? You do not let it be destructed? Same with the `path` object? It never goes out of scope or gets destructed?

Comment: My RealTimeMonitor never be destrcted,but path define as a part variable and I have correct it.Thank you for remaining.But,er...,the fails as before.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Did you know why?If I call `simulateMove(QVector<QPointF> &path)`in thread  will also be failed today.But when I use global variables by value(refer to`QVector<QPointF>` ),no problem.

Comment: without "&" before path.

Comment: That it works when you have a global non-reference variable really is an indication of scoping problems, that the referenced object gets destructed in your original code. Unless the vector is large you might consider passing it by value to the function instead, so it's copied and you won't have that problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I find just call ` pForklifts_[0]->setPos(0, 0);` will be failed.Is it can not operate GUI in non- gui thread?

Comment: Normally you should not update GUI elements in another thread than the one that created the GUI. It could definitely be an issue.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I say "without '&'" is in code `simulateMove(QVector<QPointF> &path)`.I wanna the thread pass several point to Main thread.But can't use global variable because of I need a set of point independently,no conflict with others.So value copy is best to me.But Qt's signal&slot is not support `QVector<QPointF>`.so tangled

Answer (score 1):

That's because of another thread can not operate GUI.Another problem is `connect` can not use QVector-actually difficult to use.I start a new thread in  thread which generate `QVector<QPointF>` like:

```
std::thread threadSimulateMove(&RealTimeMonitor::simulateMove, this, 
                                  forkliftId, pathLoad,pathUnload);
threadSimulateMove.detach();
```

then, **emit signals to gui thread** repeatedly and rapidly(e.g. `Sleep(20)`).